# Agama and Purana cosmology

Tags: puranas, agamas, cosmology

I have read about cosmology in Puranas as well as Agamas to an extent. What is the main difference between Puranic and Agamic cosmology? Is there any difference at all?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Which purana and which agama?

Comment: In general. Because there are differences between Purana and Agama.